# Meu primeiro script e nao consigo corrigir o erro

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Aluno 
( 
    Id_Aluno VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Rgm NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    Cpf NUMBER(11)PRIMARY KEY,
    Nm_Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Nm_Mae VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL, 
    Nm_Pai VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL, 
    Dt_Nascimento DATE NOT NULL, 
    Sexo CHAR(1), 
);

CREATE TABLE Classe
(
   CD_Classe NUMBER(8)NOT NULL,
   Vd_Aula VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Professor VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
   Nm_Nome VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
   Disciplina VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Rgm NUMBER(8)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Trabalhos VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Provas VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Notas NUMBER(2)NOT NULL
   
);
   
CREATE TABLE Matricula
(
   Dt_Matricula DATE NOT NULL,
   Ano_Letivo DATE NOT NULL,
   Serie DATE NOT NULL,
   Cd_Periodo NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
   Sg_Turma VARCHAR(3)NOT NULL,
   Rgm NUMBER(8)PRIMARY KEY 
   
);
   CONSTRAINT fk_AluMatricula FOREIGN KEY (Cpf) REFERENCES Aluno(Cpf)  
   CONSTRAINT fk_ClaMatriula FOREIGN KEY (Rgm) REFERENCES Classe(Rgm)
   
  );
```

erro

```
Erro ao iniciar na linha 1 no comando:
CREATE TABLE Aluno 
( 
    Id_Aluno VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Rgm NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    Cpf NUMBER(11)PRIMARY KEY,
    Nm_Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Nm_Mae VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL, 
    Nm_Pai VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL, 
    Dt_Nascimento DATE NOT NULL, 
    Sexo CHAR(1), 
)
Erro na Linha de Comando:11 Coluna:1
Relatório de Erro:
Erro de SQL: ORA-00904: : identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Tira a vírgula depois do Sexo CHAR(1)

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE Aluno 
( 
    Id_Aluno VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Rgm NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    Cpf NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    Nm_Nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Nm_Mae VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL, 
    Nm_Pai VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL, 
    Dt_Nascimento DATE NOT NULL, 
    Sexo CHAR(1), 
);

CREATE TABLE Classe
(
   CD_Classe NUMBER(8)NOT NULL,
   Vd_Aula VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Professor VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
   Nm_Nome VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
   Disciplina VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Rgm NUMBER(8)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Trabalhos VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Provas VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
   Notas NUMBER(2)NOT NULL
   
);
   
CREATE TABLE Matricula
(
   Dt_Matricula DATE NOT NULL,
   Ano_Letivo DATE NOT NULL,
   Serie DATE NOT NULL,
   Cd_Periodo NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
   Sg_Turma VARCHAR(3)NOT NULL,
   Rgm NUMBER(8)PRIMARY KEY 
//Tinha que definir o cpf na tabela filha para criar a chave estrangeira
       Cpf NUMBER(11), 
       //A CONSTRAINT DEFINIDA NO LUGAR INCORRETO
       CONSTRAINT fk_AluMatricula FOREIGN KEY (Cpf) REFERENCES Aluno(Cpf),  
       CONSTRAINT fk_ClaMatriula FOREIGN KEY (Rgm) REFERENCES Classe(Rgm),
    );
```